# Query different PostGIS tables in the same QGIS expression

Tags: postgis, qgis-3

I connected QGIS to my local PostGIS database, which contain several tables. It looks like this:

[image]

I dragged and dropped one of the tables to the Layers area and started visualizing one of the columns from it. With the folowing expression:

[image]

Except now I want to normalize variable "v0743" by dividing it by "v1520", a variable which from another of the PostGIS tables (namely table "v1001_2000_hf").

Is it possible to achieve this in a single expression? If so, how?

Comment: You can make a view under PostGIS and load it into QGIS (if the view has an integer unique field).

Comment: This works, thanks! Is this a "standard" way to deal with this kind of situations?

Comment: On the assumption that you have data in a postGIS database, then yes uing view tables would be the 'standard' way. However in a different setup (eg: Maybe only local file share data), the standard way may be to use a join on the layers inside of QGIS. ....Or if your data was very light and your requirement was only as a one off, you could implement this join in QGIS, even if your data is in postGIS. The right answer really depends on the volume, frequency, accessibility and publication requirements.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use PostGIS to do the work, rather than QGIS.

Download DBeaver and explore your database through that interface, including the spatial data viewer.

How are your two tables related? By a common ID or a spatial intersection? You should use SQL to not only relate the tables together, but perform the normalization.

An example might look like:

```
select 
hf.v0743 / f.v1520 as new_column_normalized
from v0001_1000_hf as hf
 left outer join v1001_200_f as f 
 on hf.COMMON_ID = f.COMMON_ID
```

Once you have your result, you can include the geometry in the selection and create a new table from the result. That new table goes into QGIS where the new_column_normalized can be visualized.